# Google Maps Polygon Drawing Shortest Distance Problem

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps Android API for Tile Overlays to display Indoor Maps. When I draw a polygon whose size is bigger than half of the image it is getting drawn in the shortest path i.e either it will go east or west. I don't want the polygon to be displayed in the shortest path.

```
PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().addAll(latngsList);                                               
 [enter image description here][1]polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.BLUE);

                          Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
                                                polygon.setVisible(true);
                                                polygon.setGeodesic(false);
                                                polygon.setZIndex(500);
                                                polygon.setStrokeColor(getColors());
```

In web we are using LeafLet Library for maps
All the coordinates are getting passed properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDZvR.png)
  In android app the points are getting marked at the exact position but the polygon is taking the shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().add(latngsList.get(0));
```

instead of

```
PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().addAll(latngsList);
```

give it a try.

Comment: No this doesn't work, irrespective of the order we give Maps will take the Shortest path, I got a workaround by forcing the Google Map to take the Longest path by adding an additional mid point between two points.